# Using fscanf to read tab delimited text file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
   Value1   Value2   Value3   Value4
    0.558    0.834    0.521    0.125
    0.543    0.800    0.231    0.222
 1.85E-01  8.0E-01  1.3E-01    0.521
 1.23E-01    0.777    0.232    0.552
  .......    .....    .....    .....
```

The file goes on to an unknown number of lines. I would like to read in all the values using `fscanf`, **excluding** the headers. I have tried the following so far:

```
fscanf(fid, '%9f %9f %9f %9f %9f %9f %9f %9f %9f %9f')
fscanf(fid, '%9f %9f %9f %9f %9f %9f %9f %9f %9f %9f',[Inf 4])
```

All give a result of:

```
ans =

     []
```

I am relatively new to the use of this command, but feel like this should be giving me the result I am looking for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got it. These commands will do the trick. The important thing to remember is that `fscanf` (somewhat confusingly) *reads* the values linewise but fills the sizeA specified array (see [doc](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html)) columnwise. Also It is necessary to move the current address of the opened file to the second line (since the first contains headers). I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this but I used `fgetl`. Please comment if you know of a better way (ie one that does not actually output the next line).

```
>> fid = fopen('textfile.txt')

fid =

     5

>> fgetl(fid)

ans =

   Value1   Value2   Value3   Value4

>> Array = fscanf(fid, '%f', [4, Inf])

Array =

    0.5580    0.5430    0.1850    0.1230
    0.8340    0.8000    0.8000    0.7770
    0.5210    0.2310    0.1300    0.2320
    0.1250    0.2220    0.5210    0.5520



>> ArrayT = Array'

ArrayT =

0.5580    0.8340    0.5210    0.1250
0.5430    0.8000    0.2310    0.2220
0.1850    0.8000    0.1300    0.5210
0.1230    0.7770    0.2320    0.5520
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your values are delimited with a single space, you can use [dlmread](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) for reading in such files.

```
>> dlmread('data.txt',' ', 2, 1)

ans =

    0.8000    0.2310    0.2220
    0.8000    0.1300    0.5210
    0.7770    0.2320    0.5520
```

The second argument is the delimiter, here I used a space. It could be tab (`\t`) or something else. The last arguments specify which row and column to start at. Here we skip the header by setting `R=2`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is helpful but the idea is to use fscanf (more flexible and adaptible to new situations which are not easily done by dlmread). Please see my answer below.

Comment: Great that you found the solution yourself!